# Duplicate Output Pso-object

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am combining `Get-ADUser` and `Get-ADComputer`, but in the environment we have 7 computers and 60 users, the output duplicates each user 3-5, any help is appreciated.

```
$outtbl = @()
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties displayname, lastlogondate

foreach ($user in $users) {
    $x = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties operatingsystem, lastlogondate |
    Select-Object name, lastlogondate, operatingsystem

    foreach ($x in $x) {
        $t = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            SamAccountName  = $user.SamAccountName
            UserDisplayname = $user.displayname
            ComputerName    = $x.Name
            operatingsystem = $x.operatingsystem
            Clastlogondate  = $x.lastlogondate
            Userlastlogon   = $user.lastlogondate
        }

        $outtbl += $t |
                   Select-Object userdisplayname, Samaccountname, userlastlogon,
                       Computername, clastlogondate, operatingsystem |
                   Export-Csv C:\result.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
    }
}
```

The output comes as

```
userdisplayname, Samaccountname, userlastlogon, Computername, clastlogondate, operatingsystem 
adminstrator,adminstrator,10/12/2017,computer1,10/12/2017,server2012
adminstrator,adminstrator,10/12/2017,computer1,10/12/2017,server2012
adminstrator,adminstrator,10/12/2017,computer1,10/12/2017,server2012
adminstrator,adminstrator,10/12/2017,computer1,10/12/2017,server2012
otheuser,user10/12/2017,server,10/12/2017,server2003
```

It should display real output.

Comment: _the output duplicates each user 3-5_ 3-5 times? baguettes? Do you have a question? If so, please edit your post and add it.

Comment: Small tip: You are obtaining `$x` (the list of computers) __every time__ foreach iterates an `$user`. You should put that line at the beginning of your spcript. It will be much faster. Also `foreach($x in $x)` should really be something like `$y in $x` or `$computer in $computers`. I'm also sure, `$outtbl` will be null, as `Export-CSV` won't output anything.

Comment: Please show a sample of desired and actual output.

Comment: output example
`userdisplayname, Samaccountname, userlastlogon, Computername, clastlogondate, operatingsystem 
    adminstrator,adminstrator,10/12/2017,computer1,10/12/2017,server2012
    adminstrator,adminstrator,10/12/2017,computer1,10/12/2017,server2012
    adminstrator,adminstrator,10/12/2017,computer1,10/12/2017,server2012
    adminstrator,adminstrator,10/12/2017,computer1,10/12/2017,server2012
    otheuser,user10/12/2017,server,10/12/2017,server2003`

Comment: What *exactly* is that "real output" it "should display"? Also, did you fix the loop variable as Clijsters pointed out?